# A question about Terraform AWS Module EventBridge

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

This is an example of an official document,
https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/eventbridge/aws/1.14.2

One of the use cases looks like this
EventBridge with schedule rule and Lambda target

```
module "eventbridge" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/eventbridge/aws"

  create_bus = false

  rules = {
    crons = {
      description         = "Trigger for a Lambda"
      schedule_expression = "rate(5 minutes)"
    }
  }

  targets = {
    crons = [
      {
        name  = "lambda-loves-cron"
        arn   = "arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-1:135367859851:function:resolved-penguin-lambda"
        input = jsonencode({"job": "cron-by-rate"})
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What does "input" above mean and what needs to be input？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `input` value is [passed to the Lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-concepts.html#gettingstarted-concepts-event) when it's invoked.

Its value is up to you (and could be empty); it depends what your Lambda function does.